# When checkbox is checked insert data if checkbox is unchecked remove data

Tags: php, html

I need help.

I want to create a system when the checkbox is checked inserts data into the database when it is unchecked it removes it from the database. Maybe there is another solution

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-9"><label for="vehicle1">Perm 1</label></div> 
    <div class="col-lg-3"><label class="switch"><input value="1" name="permchecked[]" type="checkbox"><span class="slider"></span></label></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-9"><label for="vehicle1">Usuwanie/Perm 2</label></div>  
    <div class="col-lg-3"><label class="switch"><input value="2" name="permchecked[]" type="checkbox"><span class="slider"></span></label></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-9"><label for="vehicle1">Perm 3</label></div>     
    <div class="col-lg-3"><label class="switch"><input value="3" name="permchecked[]" type="checkbox"><span class="slider"></span></label></div>
</div>
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['u_permissions_update'])){
   if (isset($permcheckeds)){ 
        foreach ($permcheckeds as $permchecked) {
            $query = $db2->prepare("INSERT INTO permissions_users SET user_id = :u_permissions_update, permissions_id= :permchecked"); 
            $query->bindValue(':u_permissions_update', $u_permissions_update);
            $query->bindValue(':permchecked', $permchecked);                     
            $query->execute();     
            $_SESSION['success']  = "Work";   
        }          
    } else {
        $_SESSION['success']  = "Not Working";   
    }  
}
```

DB permissions_users

```
permissions_users_id | permissions_id | user_id
```

[image: visualisation]

Comment: The problem starts that unchecked boxes arent in the array, so you first have to delete all ppermissions to insert them afterwords, or you could have a status field where you save the state of teh checkbox and so you can with INSERT ON DUPLICATE insert a new permission or change the status to 1 , of course here also you would prior set all staus to 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I'm not sure what javascript framework you are using if any, here is a blueprint to what you can do.

If you are planning on sending the data to the server when the switch is changed, you check the onchange for the checkbox and you don't need it to be an array. And submit the process that you want to happen along with the value of the permission to be changed.

```
var _checks = document.querySelectorAll("input[name=permchecked]");

_checks.forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener("change",function(){
    var field_data = {
      "process" : (this.checked) ? "add" : "delete",
      "permission": this.value
    };

    //using ajax, submit field_data to the server

  });
});
```

**PHP**

In your PHP, then check for process:

```
if(isset($_POST['process'])){
  if($_POST['process'] == "delete"){
  //delete from database where that permission equals the value passed plus that user. Even if the permission doesn't exist in the database already, still just run the single delete query. No reason to add an additional query to check that it exists.
 }
elseif($_POST['process'] == "add"){
  //add that permission to the database
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks BRO ! I have very little knowledge about javascript / ajax, but after reading some basic information and analyzing similar problems on stackoverflow I was able to create this script!

Comment: I had a similar problem and was browsing stackoverflow this really helped me out. Thank you